# Libgnomecanvas error when installing Ardour on Lubuntu. Gnome conflicting with LXDE?

Tags: apt, gnome, lubuntu, lxde, ardour

Don't really know if this is a question for here or the Ardour support forum, but when I try to install Ardour I get errors with libgnomecanvas. The exact error:

> The following dependencies don't meet the requirements: ardour :
>   Requirement: libgnomecanvas2-0 (>= 2.11.1) will not be installed
>   Requirement: libgnomecanvasmm-2.6-1c2a (>= 2.23.1) will not be
>   installed

I tried synaptic (and apt-get) and aptitude!

Is this solvable without installing Gnome (LXDE is more stable on my device)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Ardour 4 doesn't work with Libgnomecanvas and works perfectly with Lubuntu. The compiled version from the default ppa is Ardour 2, using a different ppa it's possible to install Ardour 4 through apt-get. The website also has some pre-compiled packages, but you'll have to pay for those.